# Should and Filter combination in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query which return the correct result

```
GET /person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "nameDetails.name.nameValue.surname": {
              "value": "Pibba",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "nameDetails.nameValue.firstName": {
              "value": "Fawsu",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the result is below:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 3.6012557,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "person",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "70002",
        "_score" : 3.6012557,
        "_source" : {
          "gender" : "Male",
          "activeStatus" : "Inactive",
          "deceased" : "No",
          "nameDetails" : {
            "name" : [
              {
                "nameValue" : {
                  "firstName" : "Fawsu",
                  "middleName" : "L.",
                  "surname" : "Pibba"
                },
                "nameType" : "Primary Name"
              },
              {
                "nameValue" : {
                  "firstName" : "Fausu",
                  "middleName" : "L.",
                  "surname" : "Pibba"
                },
                "nameType" : "Spelling Variation"
              }
            ]
          }              
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But when I add the `filter` for `Gender`, it returns no result

```
GET /person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "nameDetails.name.nameValue.surname": {
              "value": "Pibba",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "nameDetails.nameValue.firstName": {
              "value": "Fawsu",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "Male"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even I just use `filter`, it return no result

```
GET /person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "Male"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not getting any search result, because you are using the term query (in the filter clause). Term query will return the document only if it has an exact match.**

A standard analyzer is used when no analyzer is specified, which will tokenize `Male` to `male`. So either you can search for `male` instead of `Male` or use any of the below solutions.

---

If you have not defined any explicit index mapping, you need to add `.keyword` to the `gender` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `gender` field). Try out this below query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender.keyword": "Male"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66879128",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "gender": "Male",
          "activeStatus": "Inactive",
          "deceased": "No",
          "nameDetails": {
            "name": [
              {
                "nameValue": {
                  "firstName": "Fawsu",
                  "middleName": "L.",
                  "surname": "Pibba"
                },
                "nameType": "Primary Name"
              },
              {
                "nameValue": {
                  "firstName": "Fausu",
                  "middleName": "L.",
                  "surname": "Pibba"
                },
                "nameType": "Spelling Variation"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

If you have defined index mapping, then modify the mapping for `gender` field as shown below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "gender": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```